# Adding properties to Fabric Object in Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, fabricjs

When trying to extend the fabric Text object with additional parameters in Angular, I'm successful up to the part of serializing it (e.g. the new property 'fieldname' shows up in JSON). However the code fails when trying to read it back using `this.canvas.loadFromJSON`

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fromObject')

My code for the extended Object looks like this:

```
interface ITextFieldOptions extends fabric.TextOptions {
    fieldname?: string;
}

export interface TextField extends ITextFieldOptions { }

export class TextField extends fabric.Text implements ITextFieldOptions {

  public constructor(options: ITextFieldOptions) {
    options.type = 'textField';
    options.text = '{'+options.fieldname+'}';
    super('initialize', options);
  }

  toObject(propertiesToInclude?: string[]): any {
    propertiesToInclude = (propertiesToInclude || []).concat(
      ['fieldname']
    );
    return super.toObject(propertiesToInclude);
  }

}
```

What am I missing to read my extended object back to the canvas?

Comment: You need to assign TextField as `fabric.TextField`.

Comment: Declarations need to be either local or exported. Apart from this - how should it affect de-serialization? All other fabric functions seem to be working fine.

Comment: Hi, have you managed to do this? I found out that you need to overwrite fromObject method, but unfortunately I don't know how to implement it in angular/typescript.